# settings > auth dialog shows blank

Tags: facebook, authentication

The new Settings > auth dialog page is blank for one of my apps.  In other words I am unable to setup/config the new auth dialog for that app.

Yes, I have set Settings > Advanced > Enhanced Auth Dialog: Enabled but that is not actually relevant because that setting is to show the new dialog - not config it. Also, it is not enabled in my other apps and they all load the auth dialog config page correctly.

So, I can't setup nor config the new auth dialog - any ideas appreciated.

Comment: hmm, seems to be a bug http://developers.facebook.com/bugs/185086081566588

Answer (score 1):

I had this issue and it seemed to resolve itself when I setup previews for my aggregations and actually previewed them.  My auth page returned.  Not sure if that was coincidence or if it will get it back for you.  This is currently a known bug in the system and I'm sure they're working on getting it fixed without this kind of work around.

Answer (score 1):

As Dustin Nielson said, worked for me, although I didn't get it at first. So in more detail: in developer, go to apps, to your app (you might already be there), pick 'Open Graph' and then work yourself through the 'wizzard'. Leave it as is for now and try again to go to the Auth Dialog settings page.